# ASP.NET Web Api:Cannot load System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I wanna use the HosedHttpRoute class on my demo,I was trying to add reference for this class ,but neither nuget nor add assembly panel I can not find any clue to add.So how can I find this namespace?I installed all webapi package on nuget ,but still can not find.

Comment: why would you want to add this? cant you work with routes within your config files (WebApiConfig.cs)?

Comment: @user2404597 just finish my demo